# How to know, existing object limit for my current edition

Tags: custom-object, limits

I need to know existing object limit for my edition, this is not the standard limit. For my org, the limit has been exceeded by Administrator by contacting to Salesforce. However, I am keen to know existing upgraded limit by means of Apex/OOTB.

**Update: Added image after @Devendra comment.**

Here, in image, the extension is showing that, there are 222 objects. However, at custom objects it is showing 200.

[image: System Overview screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for "Number of Custom Objects Limit" from your org?

Comment: I want the number of custom objects, which i can create, not the actual available objects number.

Answer (score 7):

Navigate to Setup -> [System Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_force_com_system_overview_page.htm&language=en_US).

Here you will be able view Number of Objects you can create in your org.

[image]

Custom Object Limits as per the [Salesforce Doc](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/19/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf)

[image]

> Note:The system overview page shows usage data and limits for your
>   organization, and displays messages when you reach 95% of your limit
>   (75% of portal roles).

Comment: In my org, it is not showing actual limit that is why, I asked this question. Please refer to the screenshot added in Question.

Comment: @YsrShk As per the screenshot, it seems that you have already crossed the limit. May be you contact Salesforce support to know How many more objects they are going to allow you to create, before they actually stop allowing you from creating new one.

Comment: ok thanks.! However, i was expecting a view, where SF would show these additional limitations.

Comment: Salesforce doc is not showing those additional limits, may be you can Contact Salesforce Support. Keep us updated though!

Comment: hmm.. will try.